# tables overlap when using position abolute in css

Tags: css

I am trying to put a table within a table but they are overlapping instead. This is being caused by my css. Can someone please tell me how to get around this? When I take the absolute out or change it to relative, the page looses most of the style.

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 10px;
position: absolute;
display: table;
width: 729px;
height: 101px;
z-index: 0;
border: 1px #C0C0C0 solid;}
table.cell{
display: table-cell;}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<table  id="estimate_table" style="position: relative ! important;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <?php //print information here from previous query ?>   <br>        
        <br></td>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td><h1>Estimate</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="position: absolute ! important;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        For:<br>
                        <select name="estimate_for">                            
                        <?php
                        //sql query here and while loop to fill dropdown                            
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Job:<br><textarea name="job_name"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            Invoice#: <br>
            Date: <input type="text" name="estimate_date" value="<?php echo date('M d, Y'); ?>">                
        </td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <!--four columns with labels-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!--four columns here for user to fill form-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td> <!--skipping two columns and filling in last two in table-->         
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I ould add your code in fiddle

Comment: I'm sorry...I'm fairly new at this. What is fiddle? Do you need to see the html as well?

Comment: old habits....yeah what he said.